# How do you ping a remote server with UDP

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-core, discord, udp

So I'm trying to get the framework setup to make a discord bot that will check to see if a users dedicated server is open and update a message accordingly. I'm currently running a Minecraft and Valheim server on a separate computer in my local network.

I was trying to use the Ping class Microsoft has, but it wasn't able to ping the Valheim server. It seems like Valheim is using UDP protocol, so I've tried using the UdpClient class instead to send a message, but it remains in the "WaitingForActivation" status and I don't know what to send to get a response.

Is there a standard message that servers recognize as a ping? I've been able to ping the ports with sites that have a UDP mode, so I know for sure it is open and able to be pinged.

This is the code I'm using to attempt the ping

````
UdpClient udpPing = new UdpClient();
Byte[] sentBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Ping");

udpPing.Connect(servers[i].ip, servers[i].port);
udpPing.Send(sentBytes,sentBytes.Length);

IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, servers[i].port);
Task<UdpReceiveResult> result = udpPing.ReceiveAsync();

bool error = false;
for (int y = 0; result.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation && !error; y++)
{
    if(y == tryLimit)
    {
        error = true;
    }
}
udpPing.Close();```
````

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [Ping class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?view=netcore-3.1)?  From that page:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingTest
{
    public class PingExample
    {
        // args[0] can be an IPaddress or host name.
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions ();

            // Use the default Ttl value which is 128,
            // but change the fragmentation behavior.
            options.DontFragment = true;

            // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (data);
            int timeout = 120;
            PingReply reply = pingSender.Send (args[0], timeout, buffer, options);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString ());
                Console.WriteLine ("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
                Console.WriteLine ("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
                Console.WriteLine ("Don't fragment: {0}", reply.Options.DontFragment);
                Console.WriteLine ("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I stated in my question, I couldn't get the Ping class to work with the Valheim server. I think this because Valheim uses UDP instead of TCP protocol

Comment: standard ping doesn't use UDP or TCP, instead it uses ICMP.